# Problem Overloading Indexer in C#

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

i got a problem while overloading indexer property.

```
public class ClassName 
{
    private int[] a;
    private int[] b;
    private string[] c;
    private string[] d;

    public int this[int pos]
    {
        get{ return a[pos];}
        set{a[pos] = value;}
    }
    public int this[int pos]
    {
        get{ return b[pos];}
        set{b[pos] = value;}
    }
    public int this[int pos]
    {
        get{ return c[pos];}
        set{c[pos] = value;}
    }
    public int this[int pos]
    {
        get{ return d[pos];}
        set{d[pos] = value;}
    }
}
```

I am getting `Error 1 'Class1 variables' already defines a member called 'this' with the same parameter types`

Please suggest me how to implement this?

Comment: The problem is that you're not overloading the indexer - you've specified the same signature 4 times (also, I think two of them should return `string`). I don't think C# supports named indexers, so you might want to rethink your design.

Answer (score 3):

You defined this[] with the same signature (taking an int, returning an int) multiple times.

How does the compiler know which one to take?

Better make your arrays Properties (this time indexed properties would really come in handy!)

And make your set method for your properties private, otherwise they can overwrite the array instead of just changing values.

So to help the TS a little bit more:

```
public class Test
{
    private string[] _a;
    private int[] _b;

    public string[] A
    {
        get { return this._a; }
        private set { this._a = value; }
    }

    public int[] B
    {
        get { return this._b; }
        private set { this._b = value; }
    }

    public Test()
    {
        // todo add ctor logic here
    }
}

// now you can do:

Test t = new Test();

t.A[1] = "blah"; // assuming that index of the array is defined.
```

Good luck

Comment: I think this is maybe along the lines of what the OP was trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

Imagine this indexer being called by another class:

```
ClassName myClass = new ClassName();
myClass[0]; // Which one???
```

Answer (score 1):

The error means what it says.  You have four properties with exactly the same signature.

What are you trying to do? Show what you expect the code *using* ClassName to look like.